# Parsing XML data from nodejs

Tags: xml, node.js, parsing

Hi I have already parsed json responses in nodejs coding using the JSOn.parse(). Likewise is there anyway as to how to parse xml data? I have no idea regarding xml as i'm new in handling that.Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There's no built in xml parser, you'll need an npm module like node-xml-lite: https://npmjs.org/package/node-xml-lite